# Passing char to function var list not working

Tags: c

I need help with passing char to function's var list. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* for the exit command */
#pragma warning (disable :4996)

void AddCustomer(char phone, char firstname, char lastname, char creditcard)
{
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("Subscribers.dat", "wb");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error in opening file");
        exit(1);
    }
    fwrite(&phone, sizeof(char), 10, f);
    fwrite(" ", sizeof(char), 1, f);
    fwrite(&firstname, sizeof(char), 4, f);
    fwrite(" ", sizeof(char), 1, f);
    fwrite(&lastname, sizeof(char), 4, f);
    fwrite(" ", sizeof(char), 1, f);
    fwrite(&creditcard, sizeof(char), 10, f);
    fwrite("\n", sizeof(char), 2, f);
    fclose(f);
}

void main()
{
    char phone = "050000000";
    char firstname = "Name";
    char lastname = "Name";
    char creditcard = "0123456789";
    AddCustomer(phone, firstname, lastname, creditcard);
}
```

When I'm running this code, it is writing to the Subscribers.dat:

```
hXŒX X ŒX X  X|X |X
```

and it should write `050000000 Name Name 0123456789`

Comment: You need to pass `char *` and not `char`.  Then you won't need the `&` in the calls to `fwrite()`. However, you also need to worry about how long the strings you're writing are.  Credit card numbers are normally 16 digits long, for example. Names are frequently longer than 4 characters.  You should pay attention to your compiler warnings; it must be telling you about type mismatches between the function definition and the function call.

Comment: `char` holds a single character, not an array of characters (string). Do `char *phone`, etc., instead to declare pointers to the strings.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but `main` should return `int`, not `void`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code

**Point 1**

```
  char phone = "050000000";
```

to

```
 char phone[ ] = "050000000";
```

because, you need an **array** to hold the *characters*.

similarly for others.

**Point 2**

```
void AddCustomer(char phone, char firstname, char lastname, char creditcard)
```

to

```
void AddCustomer(char *phone, char *firstname, char *lastname, char *creditcard)
```

because, you need to pass the array, not a single `char`.

**Point 3**

```
fwrite(&phone, sizeof(char), 10, f);
```

to

```
fwrite(phone, sizeof(char), 10, f);
```

data type has changed now, no need of `&` here.

similarly for others.

Note: The recommended signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to pass a *string* to a function (it's called *an array of char*), you need to use `char *` instead of `char` as `char` is only for handling *a single character*.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* for the exit command */
#pragma warning (disable :4996)

void AddCustomer(char *phone, char *firstname, char *lastname, char *creditcard)
{
    // other code
    // use fwrite(phone, sizeof(char), 10, f); instead of fwrite(&phone, sizeof(char), 10, f);
    // do the same for every line of code with the variables you're passing to this function
    // remove the &s
}

int main()
{
    char *phone = "050000000";
    char *firstname = "Name";
    char *lastname = "Name";
    char *creditcard = "0123456789";
    AddCustomer(phone, firstname, lastname, creditcard);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `char` is a single character. Not a string. What you are looking for are CStrings. These are basically arrays of char (which are null-Terminated (`\0`)):

```
char cstring[] = "Foobar";
char single = 'a';
char * string = malloc(10*sizeof(char));
strcpy(string, "Foobar!"); // Caution: Better use strncpy!
```

The you can pass it (both `string` and `cstring`) to a function like this:

```
void DoSomething(char * name) {
    printf("Name: %s\n", name);
}
```

When initializing a CString directly like in the `cstring` case, it will be automatically `\0`-Terminated, also in the `strcpy` case, but `strcpy` wont take care of checking if the destination array has enough space, so it will easily mess up your memory. To be sure, use functions which only copy n-Characters like `strncpy`, so you wont mess up your memory.

You should look into C Basics!